# ARRAYFORMULA to SUM previous row column and current row column

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wlWqdFwgv90s50iP-bXXBHciyualohj610qFiSatcmQ/edit?usp=sharing

Shared the above sheet with example. I want an arrayformula to sum the previous rows column and current row column.

Comment: You already have a formula in your cells which works well, why do you want to change it?

Comment: Its a formula given by others. Any hiwt, I've clearly mentioned my requirements where I don't want to go with drag formula..

Comment: There should be some misunderstanding, array formula is not to avoid drag formulas, it's about performing complex calculations. You can fill the whole column also with your current formula to avoid the need of dragging it always (I'm not familiar with google, in Excel: select last cell with formula, press CTRL+SHIFT+DOWN then press CTRL+D), or again in Excel you can insert a table and there formula is autofilled when you add a new row, but I don't know whether google has similar functionality.

Comment: I've lot of sheets with this requirement and I can't do the same in all the sheets which takes a lot of time.

Comment: Sorry that was all I could help.

Comment: I think the only way to do this in one column would be by writing a script

Comment: @Akshin, could you provide that script

Comment: Check my updated unswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In F2 I entered this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(row(B2:B)=2, B2, if(len(B2:B)+len(C2:C), mmult(transpose(if(transpose(row(B2:C))>=row(B2:C),if(B2:B<>"", B2:B,0)+(if(C2:C<>"", C2:C,0)*-1), 0)),row(B2:B)^0),)))
```

But.. in order for this formula to work you will have to write your 'starting' balance in B2. See also the spreadsheet you shared.

I hope that helps ?

Comment: Can you update the formula in such a way that I may have value in either B or c and my formula must work. To explain, I may enter value in income column or expense column or in both columns. Hope you understood.

Comment: I updated the formula so that it now should work if only one column is filled in. See if that works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it via Script.

```
function calcBalance(range,InitialBalance){
  var total = [];
  total[0] = InitialBalance;
  for (var i=2;i<range.length;i++) {
    if (range[i][0] !== "") {
      total[i-1] = range[i][0]-range[i][1]+total[i-2];
      }
  }
  total = total.slice(1);
  return (total);
}
```

In cell **D3** type

```
=calcBalance(B:C,D2)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You forgot to delete other values in Columd D, so I did it for you

Comment: Your function worked, but for each change, i see the column is showing as "loading" and seems it will take a lot of time to calculate when I have more rows. Any how thanks for the semi fix.